# Generate custom number of lorem ipsum words in HTML

Tags: sublimetext3, lorem-ipsum

With `lorem` + <kbd>TAB</kbd> I am able to generate some random words.

```
<body>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmodtempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodoconsequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit essecillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat nonproident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</body>
```

Now I want to generate more number of words, say 100 sentences of lorem text. Is there any way to do it in Sublime Text 3?

Comment: https://github.com/billymoon/LoremIpsum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sublime text 3 - [refer to this github link for detailed steps](https://github.com/ccpalettes/sublime-lorem-text/tree/sublime-text-3-beta)

> LoremText 3 is a plugin for sublime text 3 that creates random/fixed lorem ipsum text.

I recommend to visit the github page but still if you are interested in a brief overview of it, here it is -

1. Download the extension (git way)

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/ccpalettes/sublime-lorem-text.git
   git checkout sublime-text-3-beta
   ```
2. Then open "Packages" directory through `Preferences -> Browse Packages...` and select the downloaded package (for linux)
3. Usage

> There are a few ways to use the LoremText plugin.
>
> Just press the shortcut key (`alt+l` on all platforms) to insert some
> lorem ipsum text. Type `lorem({word_count}, {paragraph_count})` in your
> file, make sure that the input curosr is within the region of the
> `lorem{?, ?}` expression, then press the shortcut key (`alt+l`). Parameter
> "word_count" represents how many paragraphs to insert and parameter
> "paragraph_count" represents how many words that each paragraph
> contains. For example, `lorem(100, 3)` means that it will create three
> paragraphs of lorem ipsum text and each paragraph contains one hundred
> words. Both the two parameters are optional, if you leave them empty,
> the plugin will use default values that are configured in the settings
> file. Select menu entry `Edit -> Lorem Text...`, active the sub-menu
> commands. Go to Command Palette, find "Lorem Text" command.

Answer (score 3):

type `lorem100` for example

A number after Lorem gives you the number of Lorem characters

Comment: Tried in sublime text 3, not working. I guess it worked for me in phpstorm before.

Comment: in vscode this command work very well, if you can use vscode instead of sublime text

Comment: Why do you give a VSCode solution for a question about SublimeText?

Comment: If you're using react and vscode, then you need to make sure that your file extension is in `.jsx` not `js`. otherwise it won't work as expected